# attaching information for table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data logging application for which i have created  a table as shown below -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `waterheater`.`heatertest550001_data`
` (
    `Index_Records` INT(10)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Time_Stamp` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `Water_Temperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Body_Temperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Body_Shell_Top_Temperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Body_Shell_Bottom_Temperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ambient_Temperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Voltage` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Current` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Wattage` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Energy` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Power_Factor` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `Notice` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `LVTIMESTAMP` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Index_Records`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `INDEX_UNIQUE` (`Index_Records`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

And to attach information for the same table I'm creating another table as follows -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `waterheater`.`heatertest550001_info` (
    `Index_Records` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ReportNumber` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ProjectNumber` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TestDiscipline` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'Electrical',
    `Customer` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Manufacturer` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Program` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'NABL',
    `TestLabLocation` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '(b)UL Manesar',
    `ItemUnderTest` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'Storage Electrical Water Heater',
    `Model` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `NumberOfSamples` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `SampleIdentification` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ManufacturerSerialNumber` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTCondition` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `DateOfReceipt` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `ApplicableStandard` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'IS2082:1993 & IS 302-2-21:1992',
    `DateOfTestingStartDate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `DateOfTestingStopDate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `DurationSecondsOfTesting` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `DurationTestText` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `LabAmbientTemperature` FLOAT DEFAULT '23',
    `LabAmbientHumidity` FLOAT DEFAULT '70',
    `DateOfReporting` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    `TestIncharge` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `GeneralRemarks` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedVoltage` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedCurrent` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedFrequency` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedPower` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedCapacity` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTApplianceSort` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'Class 1',
    `IUTRatedWaterProofDegree` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'IP X4',
    `IUTRatedPressure` FLOAT DEFAULT '0.80',
    `IUTApplianceType` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `IUTRatedStandingLoss` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcWaterTemperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcAmbientTemperature` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcVoltage` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcCurrent` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcFrequency` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcPower` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcCapacity` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcApplianceSort` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'Class 1',
    `CalcRatedWaterProofDegree` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'IP X4',
    `CalcPressure` FLOAT DEFAULT '0.80',
    `CalcApplianceType` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcStandingLoss` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcStandingLossRate` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `CalcStandingLoss24h` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `EnergyConsumptionTest` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `EnergyConsumption24h` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    `MaxRecords` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Index_Records`),
    UNIQUE KEY `Index_Records_UNIQUE` (`Index_Records`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. Can somebody help! and thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, it seems to be around data modelling, but without more information, how could we propose a structure? It's also unclear what the formal relationship between the tables are, you are going to need to put more work into the question to make it answerable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew
`heatertest550001_data` is actual table huge number of records while `heatertest550001_info` is having only one number of records while I don't want to create two tables as _info table is just information related to _data table, why should another table be created just for one record.